# TinyMCE print plugin

Tags: javascript, printing, tinymce

I'm trying to add print plugin to my TinyMCE widget, but it doesn't work :

```
var option_tinymce = {
    script_url : '/ui/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js',
    plugins: "code autosave insertdatetime textcolor print",
    toolbar1: "print code | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent | undo redo | removeformat | forecolor backcolor | formatselect | restoredraft",
    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    language: 'fr_FR',
    setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('change', function(e) {
                $(editor.formElement).find('[name="modification_form"]').val("Yes");
            });
    },
    skin: 'pvx_light',
    content_css: "/ui/css/style.css, /ui/css/style_tiny.css",
    schema: "html5",
    autosave_restore_when_empty: false,
    resize : 'both'
}
```

Comment: You got any error? If yes, please include it here!

Comment: What version of TinyMCE are you using?  Can you make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows the issue in running code?

Comment: it's ok. it was a mistake of a colleague. ty